# A rule in Outlook Webmail for all email addresses with a certain domain suffix?

Tags: outlook.com, spam-prevention, email-rules

Currently, I'm being bombarded with spam emails that follow a certain format in their address: x@cars-from-xx.us
(x) & (xx) = a random name, like Tom, or Jeff.
The domain name is always changing, but the domain suffix is constant. After some snooping around, I tried my hand at creating a rule that would automatically delete emails with that specific suffix:
"**After the message arrives and...**
the sender's address contains these words: '0.us' or '9.us' or '8.us' or '7.us' or '6.us' or '5.us' or '4.us' or '3.us' or '2.us' or '1.us' or 'z.us' or 'y.us' or 'x.us' or 'w.us' or 'v.us' or 'u.us' or 't.us' or 's.us' or 'r.us' or 'q.us' or 'p.us'or...
and the message was sent to '(my email)'

**Do the following...**
delete the message
and stop processing more rules on this message"

And it did not work at all, as I realized the individual letters and numbers I added are interpreted as complete domains, and not part of a domain, so in the rule above for example, by blocking '0.us', the rule would only apply to emails like this: john@0.us, and not: john@cars0.us

How do I block emails coming from a specific suffix to a domain?